# scrapy not crawling if i have httpstatus field in

Tags: python, scrapy

If i put in the **handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 400, 403, 404]** *(any http status code)* it is not crawling...

if i comment it it will crawl..

part of my **scrapy.py**

```
class SSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'seeker'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 400, 403, 404]
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
       item = SpiderItem()
       url = response.url
       item['url'] = response.url
       item['redirect_status'] = response.status

       ...

       item['redirects'] = 0
       if 301 <= response.status <= 308:
            item['redirects'] += 1

       yield item


    ....
```

it doesn't crawl if i have 3xx http codes in...only the 4xx codes.
And i don't think it counts the 3xx redirects if i dont put them in that list.

Comment: can you put your log please

Comment: My log doesn't have any do errors